# Looking for historical data for WWII era navy fleet makeups

Tags: data-request

I am searching for:

- Listing of naval vessels (specifically during WWII 1939-1945 timeframe)
- Relevant information such as name, class, country, commission/launch dates, sinking, etc

[This site](http://www.cna.org/centers/operations-tactics/ship-database) has *some* historical data in its Excel file for the United States but not everything.

Answer (score 1):

There's a surprisingly comprehensive list of ships, naval equipment, and vessels for WWII at the [World War II Database](http://ww2db.com/ship.php).  You can search by type of vessel ([destroyer](http://ww2db.com/ship.php?list=D)) or by country ([Germany](http://ww2db.com/ship.php?q=4&list=c)).  There is also detailed information about each vessel mentioned (such as the U.S. [Casabianca submarine](http://ww2db.com/ship_spec.php?ship_id=S387)).

Comment: Hmm. That is helpful but is missing a significant percentage of ships...